# NullReferenceException experienced with Owin on Startup .Net Core 2.0 - Settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin, nancy

I'm trying to start up a WebApp to use with NancyFx in a .NET Core 2.0 project.

The package i've added to the solution to do this is

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

which installs it's dependencies:

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
>
> Microsoft.Owin
>
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
>
> Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
>
> Newtonsoft.Json
>
> Owin

I've also added:

> Nancy
>
> Nancy.Owin

My project is of type "xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)".

Starting with my test class, we have:

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _webApp;
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:1234";

    public MyIntegrationTests()
    {
        _webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: Url);
    }
```

My startup class looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

I also have a NancyModule with a test route:

```
public class TestModule : NancyModule
{
    public TestModule()
    {

        Get("/test", args => "test");
    }
}
```

However, when starting my Integration Tests module (by trying to run any test within it), i am met with a Null Reference Exception.
This is the stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.FromConfigImplementation..ctor()
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.b__0()
>     at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.LoadFromConfig(IDictionary`2 settings)
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext..ctor(StartOptions options)
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
>
> at [redacted].IntegrationTests.MyIntegrationTests..ctor() in C:\Users[redacted]\source\repos[redacted].IntegrationTests\MyIntegrationTests.cs:line 21

---

What i've tried:

1. Adding packages one by one, with varying versions.
2. Changing my Startup Class to add a HttpConfiguration
3. Clearing localhost cookies (was suggested in other topics here)
4. Using this guide: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin#katana---httplistener-selfhost i receive the exact same error as previously.

To me, it looks like there is a configuration missing - or not being found. However, everything i refer to exists. Any ideas?
(Worth mentioning - this test project has no appsettings.json, web.config, etc)

EDIT: Test project available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1bw5pu9t0e9fwt/NancyOwinTest.zip?dl=0
Making the test project, i realise it's restoring packages at the .NET 4.6.1 level, rather than .NET Core.
I may well be making a stupid mistake, but which one, i haven't figured out yet.

Comment: did you follow the steps for Katana - HttpListener (SelfHost)?  https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin   check <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" ....

Comment: I've adjusted my question above with that info now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems the way i was doing this was not possible, due to compatibility issues.
However, i stumbled upon a way to configure the csproj file directly to reference the correct packages, here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2863#issuecomment-365107613

Copying config here incase that goes down:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AssemblyName>nancydemo</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>nancydemo</PackageId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <StartupObject>NancyApplication.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0-barneyrubble" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In combination with the startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
    }
}
```

and the main test run snippet above replaced with:

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IWebHost _webApp;
        private const string Url = "http://localhost:1234";

        public MyIntegrationTests ()
        {
            _webApp = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(Url)
                .Build();

            _webApp.Start();
        }
```

The NancyModule stayed the same:

```
public class TestModule : NancyModule
{
    public TestModule()
    {

        Get("/test", args => "test");
    }
}
```

This now works for my needs! (A basic 'server' responding to requests for test purposes)

Comment: `Nancy` is no longer being maintained. :-(